# why is xcode giving me this warning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4

here is the code I am making a UISearchBar programmatically

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,30)];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:searchBar]; 
}
```

Comment: What's the warning?

Comment: This sort of code usually goes in -(void) viewDidLoad {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it maybe your class doesn't conform to `UISearchBarDelegate`? Change you class declaration from

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
...
@end
```

to

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject<UISearchBarDelegate>
...
@end
```

Anyway, what's the warning?

Comment: local decleration of searchbar hides instance variables

Comment: the argument `searchBar` to your method has the same name as your instance variable `searchBar`. rename one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the warning. However, I can still make an assumption that it's one of the following two possibilities:

1. A warning on the line `searchBar = [[UISearchBar...` saying something about types. This may indicate that `searchBar` isn't defined correctly as a `UISearchBar*`.
2. A warning on the line `searchBar.delegate = self`, saying something about `id<UISearchBarDelegate>`. The problem here is that your current class never declared itself as conforming to the `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol. In this case, you need to amend your `@interface` declaration like so: `@interface MyClass : MySuperclass <UISearchBarDelegate>`

Comment: local decleration of searchbar hides instance variables : thanks for that I tryed that but it still gives me warning :(

Comment: You don't have a local declaration of searchbar in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

1- @interface YourClassName : ParentClass < UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property UISearchBar *srchBar;

@end

2- @synthesize srchBar; // in the .m file

3- [self.srchBar setDelegate:self];  // in viewDidLoad

4- [srchBar resignFirstResponder];  //  resign THIS WAY!